# Change the model in OnActionExecuting event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, action-filter

I'm using Action Filter in MVC 3.

My question is if I can crafting the model before it's passed to the ActionResult in OnActionExecuting event?

I need to change one of the properties value there.

Thank you,

Comment: Could you explain why you'd need to do this? I suspect there's a better way to accomplish what you need.

Comment: One of the model properties determines how the view will look like: Editor or Display and I want to set it according to the user permissions

Comment: why do you want to keep something like this dependent on model property. instead you should check the user permission inside the view and decide which template to render (editor or display)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's no model yet in the `OnActionExecuting` event. The model is returned by the controller action. So you have a model inside the `OnActionExecuted` event. That's where you can change values. For example if we assume that your controller action returned a ViewResult and passed it some model here's how you could retrieve this model and modify some property:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
        if (result == null)
        {
            // The controller action didn't return a view result 
            // => no need to continue any further
            return;
        }

        var model = result.Model as MyViewModel;
        if (model == null)
        {
            // there's no model or the model was not of the expected type 
            // => no need to continue any further
            return;
        }

        // modify some property value
        model.Foo = "bar";
    }
}
```

If you want to modify the value of some property of the view model that's passed as action argument then I would recommend doing this in a custom model binder. But it is also possible to achieve that in the `OnActionExecuting` event:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var model = filterContext.ActionParameters["model"] as MyViewModel;
        if (model == null)
        {
            // The action didn't have an argument called "model" or this argument
            // wasn't of the expected type => no need to continue any further
            return;
        }

        // modify some property value
        model.Foo = "bar";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you maybe know how can I get the action's passed parametrs like the ActionDescriptor.ActionParameters in OnActionExecuting event?

Comment: That's what I've showed in my answer: `filterContext.ActionParameters["parameterName"]`.

Comment: In your previous comment you said that you were in the `OnActionExecuting` method. The `OnActionExecuted` method is invoked after the action has completed running so it doesn't really make sense to modify its input parameters.

Comment: I think i'm not clear enough, so let me be more clear: The first thing was to modify the model as you show me. The second issue is to read the action parameters and this is what I want to do now...

Comment: You have no access to action parameters in the `OnActionExecuted` method. That's because there's no action anymore when this method executes. The action has finished. From the `filterContext.ActionDescriptor` property you could get the list and the type of each argument but not the value. One possibility is to store the values that you need to access in the HttpContext inside the `OnActionExecuting` method and then retrieve them in the `OnActionExecuted` method from the HttpContext.

Comment: Can filtercontext result be type casted to dynamic model? I need to access one property of model in OnActionExecuted method. For each model this property name/type would be same, but model is different for each action.