# Filtering Data from the Controller and Passing it to the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a small scenario :

I fetch data from the database and I want to filter it in my ActionExecuted Filter and then send it to the View. I am accessing the fetched data from the Database using TempData, in my Filter. After I modify the data inside my Filter I want to send it to the View.
What are the possible solutions for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify your `TempData` inside `OnActionExecuted` method of your custom filter the view will get that modified `TempData` by design.

Example:

Filter:

```
public class MyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.TempData["key"] += "modified";
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[MyFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TempData["key"] = "some_value";

        return View();
    }
}
```

View(Index.cshtml):

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @TempData["key"]
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When you run this you will see `Index` page showing modified data pulled from `TempData`.

Here is some [article explaining action filters feature](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I not using TempData in my View. I am using : @model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CountryVM> in my View and then I Enumerate the Model to present the view. Is it possible to update this Model object in my Filter ?  The workflow I am thinking is as follow : Before my object gets sent to the view let me catch it in filter, modify and then pass to view. Also can I access objects in Filter without using TempData, ViewBag that are created in Controllers ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify/edit your scenario. You wrote that you have your data inside `TempData` ...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I had to use TempData in order to access my country object inside Filter as suggested by peoples in SO.
The workflow I am thinking is as follow : Before my object gets sent to the view let me catch it in filter, modify and then pass to view. Also can I access objects in Filter without using TempData, ViewBag that are created in Controllers ?

Comment: Yes. You may acces models. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416951/change-the-model-in-onactionexecuting-event

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had been looking for this approach for days :D